# Performance tweak in Pagination (SQL Query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `select` query with multiple joins and conditions. Lets say that this table has a large number of records (>5000). In my app, I am using pagination with the following added at the end of the query:

```
OFFSET 5 * (1 - page) ROWS
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

where `page` is the current page that the user is viewing.
However, this has become quite slow, about 5 seconds per query. I have thought about using, instead of this, the `top` keyword. For instance, for page 2, I would do a `top 10` and, in the `C#` side, discard the first 5 rows. However, for late pages, it would obviously be as slow as the previous approach.

Is there anything more feasible?

The query is, while big, quite simple being a bunch of `likes` and such.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is the offset? A bunch of likes are probably the cause of the slow performance. Have you check the explain plan?

Answer (score 0):

I forget where I first saw this suggested, so I don't have a link, but I have had success by doing the pagination on a Primary-Key-only CTE, and then joining that back to the tables to get the data.

So something like this:

```
WITH Ord_CTE AS (
 SELECT {primary key column(s)}
 FROM {tables and joins}
 WHERE {conditions}
 ORDER BY {column(s)} OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY
)
SELECT {all the columns I want}
FROM {tables and joins}
INNER JOIN Ord_CTE ON {primary key column(s)}
ORDER BY {column(s)}
```

I don't promise this will work in your case (I've used in cases that were more complicated requiring dynamic ordering and paging), but it's worth trying.

Comment: Are you sure that make difference? I try with a dataset with 1000 rows using https://mockaroo.com/  and didnt see any difference with a simple `select * `  with offset

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it makes a difference if the problem in the original case is that it is doing extra work per row (such as lookups) for rows that are ultimately discarded. It isn't clear this is the case here or not though

Comment: Right, the question just mentions "multiple joins and conditions", so I'm not sure if it will be helped by this technique or not.   I would not expect using this technique to make a difference in a very simple query.